# Should I choose "for" or "of a" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> A top tier choice for a camera

or

> A top tier choice of a camera

Please explain why at the same time

Comment: Can you provide us a full sentence - that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it would be more likely heard as "choice of camera" than "choice of a camera".

> A top tier choice for a camera.

This sounds more general, and focuses more on the particular camera as a great choice, highlighting its top tier qualities.

The word "choice" could easily be replaced by the word "option" or "candidate" and still sound reasonably idiomatic.

The "a camera" refers more to the general idea/institution of selecting a camera: "A top tier choice for the selecting of a camera."

> A top tier choice of camera.

This sounds more concrete, and focuses more on the choosing (and excluding of other options). I think you'd be more likely to hear this after a choice has been made, e.g., "That was a good choice of camera." Or even, "That is a good choice of camera," sounds to me like the speaker has heard reviews from other people who've already chosen it. "That's a good choice for a camera" makes the speaker sound less certain somehow.

Notice also that our generalised sentence makes much less sense here:

> A top tier choice of the selecting of a camera.

What would I go for personally? To me, it sounds like the context is an advertisment, so I'd use:

> A top tier choice for a camera.